# trouble in html jquery in fixing the height of div container

Tags: jquery, html, css

i was trying to do this, i have 3 columns in a container using div, we can say each of 33%. what i want to do is to have the same height of each 3 columns equal to the height of column that have maximum height with out fixing the height(that is as we know div element takes the height automatically depending upon the content in it, so if we have 3 columns of different height because of different content in it then how can i do the same height equal to the column that have maximum height) but not able to do it.
So please tell me how can i do this?

Comment: Just get height of each column in different variables and compare which one is max. Then just assign the same to all the divs. Simple.

Comment: that's what i did, it's ok for a limit i.e. if we have 3 or 5 column but if we have 10 or 20 or more columns then it will become lengthy to first taking height of all columns in different variables then to compare it,that's what my sir said to me. is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: @prateekjain The way I said will work.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it like this.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="col">asd</div>
    <div class="col">asdasdasd
        <br />asdas
        <br />asdasd
        <br />asdasd
        <br />asdasd</div>
    <div class="col">asd</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.con {
    height: 100%;
    width: 400px;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.col {
    display: table-cell;
    border: #000000 solid 1px;
}
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/SM8x3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is something total css based, hope it helps

http://jsfiddle.net/SM8x3/7/

HTMl

```
  <ul class="list-wrapper">
    <li class="list-item">asd</li>
    <li class="list-item">asd</li>
    <li class="list-item">asdasdasd <br />asdas <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdas <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdas <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdas <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdasd
    </li>
    <li class="list-item">asd</li>
    <li class="list-item">asd</li>
    <li class="list-item">asdasdasd <br />asdas <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdas <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdas <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdas <br />asdasd <br />asdasd <br />asdasd
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS

```
 .list-wrapper { 
    border-left:1px solid #DADADA;
    border-right: 1px solid #DADADA;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #DADADA;
    overflow: hidden;    
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width: 450px;
 }
 .list-wrapper:after, .list-wrapper:before {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DADADA;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 33.3%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
.list-wrapper:after {
  left: 66.7%;
}
.list-item {
 border-top: 1px solid rgb(218, 218, 218);
 display: list-item;
 float: left;
 list-style-type: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding:10px 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 33.3%;
}
.list-wrapper:nth-child(3n+1){
 clear: left;
}
```

Comment: So much unneeded CSS in this.

Comment: thnk u friends for ur suggestions :)